# How to setup ILC Agent in Volttron-GS?

Tags: volttron

I am fairly new to Volttron. I am interested in installing & running ILC agent present in Volltron-GS directory.

I couldn't find any documentation/Office-Hours related to this. Can someone share it, if there is any.

Also How can I install and run this Agent?

[image: ILC Agent in Volttron-GS]

Answer (score 0):

The VOLTTRON-GS repository is not part of the VOLTTRON Core repository, so I am not sure of the state of this codebase in general, however, given that it is an agent, I would expect that it could be installed following the general agent installation process:  1) Generate an agent config file if necessary.  I cannot guide you on how to do this for this agent as I am not familiar with the code nor does the agent have a README, however it is possible that it may not need a config file at all.  2)  Use `vctl install <path to the agent> -c <path to config file if applicable> --tag <tag>` to install the agent with a default configuration.  3) Run `vctl start --tag <tag>` to start the agent running on the platform.

These instructions are using a simple case VOLTTRON installation, and will differ if connecting the agent remotely, etc.